# jquery validation engine position arrow centerRight

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validation-engine

How can I put the arrow in Right Center position?
Or how can I manually move the TopRight to CenterRight position?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make custom settings on jquery validation engine and add $("#formID1").validationEngine({promptPosition : "topRight:-100"}); while validating.